# Getting ImportError: cannot import name SRV in ROS

Tags: python, server, python-import, ros

I have a `ROS` server `MY_Warning` and I have the file `node/srv/MY_Warning.srv` which contains:

```
typ1 var1
typ2 var2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
typ3 var3
```

in `node/src/subdir/main.py` (which contains the server) I have `from node.srv import MY_Warning, MY_WarningResponse` but I'm getting:

```
    from node.srv import MY_Warning, MY_WarningResponse
ImportError: cannot import name EOR_Warning
```

while `rossrv show MY_Warning` shows me the correct/expected thing:

```
$ rossrv show MY_Warning
[node/MY_Warning]:
typ1 var1
typ2 var2
---
typ3 var3
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here? I don't get it...

Comment: i think you wanna read the file not import it. what do u want from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am i missing something? The missing error for import and the import statements do not match. The module in the error message is not the one imported

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same error. In other questions, the route of the error was a naming issue.  Don't think it is in your case, even if in your error `EOR_Warning` appears, You should get My_Warning.

Check if the ouotput of `ls devel/include/node/`. Can you see the headers?

Try:

```
catkin_make clean
catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps node
rosrun node main.py
```

And try again to import the ROS service. This solved my problem.